# How to get all values from a column in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

You see, I'm trying to add the quantity if the item name already exists in the DataGridView. So what I did was made a for loop to check each row in the DataGridView. What it did was just add more rows.

```
for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    if (dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == dataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString())
    {
        dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value = int.Parse(dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) + 1;
        dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataTable.Rows[0][4].ToString()) * Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        quantity = 1;
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(quantity, dataTable.Rows[0][2], dataTable.Rows[0][4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to check every Item name without going through a for loop

Comment: i think it is better to use foreach. but you need to iterate through all elements to compare for name or sth. so the answer is no

Comment: Where will the quantity field be located, in a new row or in a new column?

Comment: @a.azemia they're all in a predefined column already. I'm just changing the value of it. For instance, there' are two Mozzarella Sticks for $1 (1 qty). I input the same thing again and it should changed to $2 (2 qty). If that makes sense.

Comment: The first row of the DataGridView is fine. It changes Qty and the Price. But as soon as the second item is inputted again, it just produces another row

Comment: Is this  correct dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == dataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString()

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to using .ToLower() or .ToUpper() in string comparation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I just made a checker using a for loop!

```
for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView.Rows.Count; x++)
{
     if (dataGridView.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == dataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString())
     {
          same = true;
          counter = x;
     }
}
if (same == true)
{
     dataGridView.Rows[counter].Cells[0].Value = int.Parse(dataGridView.Rows[counter].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) + 1;
     dataGridView.Rows[counter].Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dataTable.Rows[0][4].ToString()) * Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView.Rows[counter].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
else
{
    quantity = 1;
    dataGridView.Rows.Add(quantity, dataTable.Rows[0][2], dataTable.Rows[0][4]);
}
```